# cryptojs and golang give different sha3 hash values

Tags: javascript, go, cryptojs, sha-3

I'm trying to generate a sha3-512 hash in JS and check it in a golang server. However, cryptoJS is producing different hashes than golang.

CryptoJS:

```js
CryptoJS.algo.SHA3.create().update("foo").finalize().toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
```

Output:

`1597842aac52bc9d13fe249d808afbf44da13524759477404c3592ee331173e89fe1cbf21a7e4360990d565fad4643cdb209d80fa41a91dea97e665022c92135`

---

Golang:

```golang
hex.EncodeToString(crypto.SHA3_512.New().Sum([]byte("foo")))
```

Output:

`666f6fa69f73cca23a9ac5c8b567dc185a756e97c982164fe25859e0d1dcc1475c80a615b2123af1f5f94c11e3e9402c3ac558f500199d95b6d3e301758586281dcd26`

I expect these hashes to be equal, but they aren't

Comment: Funny enough, i get a third value with Python‘s `hashlib.sha3_512(b“foo“).hexdigest()`...

Comment: Assuming your Go package implements [hash.Hash](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash) you have to call Write before Sum (passing the hash input to Sum is nonsensical).

Comment: FWIW attempting to do `h.Sum(data)` is a *very* common mistake. I have fixed the same bug in 3 different code bases in 2 companies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, your output is 134-width which should be 128-width.

Let us decode your output:

```
bytes, _ := hex.DecodeString("666f6fa69f73cca23a9ac5c8b567dc185a756e97c982164fe25859e0d1dcc1475c80a615b2123af1f5f94c11e3e9402c3ac558f500199d95b6d3e301758586281dcd26")
fmt.Printf("%s\n", bytes)
```

We found the output is `foo��s̢:��ȵg�Zun�ɂO�XY����G\���:���L��@,:�X������u��(�&`.

That means what you did actually is to output:

"foo" + sha3("")

where sha3_512("") is "a69f73cca23a9ac5c8b567dc185a756e97c982164fe25859e0d1dcc1475c80a615b2123af1f5f94c11e3e9402c3ac558f500199d95b6d3e301758586281dcd26" from [Examples of SHA-3 variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know whose sha3 package you're using.  Here's what I get with [this code](https://play.golang.org/p/fEI1gUwLycu):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/sha3"
)

func main() {
    h := sha3.New512()
    h.Write([]byte("foo"))
    sum := h.Sum(nil)
    fmt.Printf("hash = %x\n", sum)
}
```

`hash = 4bca2b137edc580fe50a88983ef860ebaca36c857b1f492839d6d7392452a63c82cbebc68e3b70a2a1480b4bb5d437a7cba6ecf9d89f9ff3ccd14cd6146ea7e7`

Compare with Python3:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> print(hashlib.sha3_512(b"foo").hexdigest())
```

which prints:

`4bca2b137edc580fe50a88983ef860ebaca36c857b1f492839d6d7392452a63c82cbebc68e3b70a2a1480b4bb5d437a7cba6ecf9d89f9ff3ccd14cd6146ea7e7`